# Using selectorLabels include for multi-pod helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I used `helm create myapp` (Helm 3) to get started, but my chart has multiple pod deployments, each performing a different function. What would be the best way to restructure the default code for multi-pod support, especially how to change the generated `selectorLabels` macro?  Assuming I have two deployments `foo` and `bar`.

My first step was to change `values.yaml` into sections:

```yaml
foo:
  image: fooimage:1.0
  ...
bar:
  image: barimage:1.0
  ...
```

Also rename/copy `deployment.yaml` into `foo.yaml` and `bar.yaml`, and add `{{- with .Values.foo }}` (and `.bar`) to the top of them to change the scope - this way both deployment files can use `.image` instead of `.foo.image` / `.bar.image`.

Next I tried to modify the selector label generator:

```golang
{{- define "myapp.selectorLabels" -}}
app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "myapp.name" . }}
app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
{{- end }}
```

The above is used in the deployment in `selector.matchLabels` and `template.metadata.labels`, e.g.

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "myapp.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
```

With the scope changed, I had to use `$` instead of the `.`, but that generates identical labels for both deployments. What would be the recommended way to generate labels differently for each pod, while maybe prefixing them with the chart name, perhaps like this?:

```yaml
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
      app.kubernetes.io/component: foo
```